# Hibernate - @ManyToOne on Entities that extends from Abstract class

Tags: spring, hibernate, inheritance, entity, discriminator

I have a similar structure already existing in my database and it has many data:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Person {
    @Id
    Long id;
    @Column(name="COMMONFIELD")
    String commonField;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "WOMAN")
public class Woman extends Person {
   .....       
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "MAN")
public class Man extends Person {
   .....       
}
```

This code will work with two different tables WOMAN and MAN where both will contain the common fields defined in the abstract class Person.

Now I will like to have a class Car that has an owner which can be either a woman or a man. A person can also be the owner of several cars. So I declare it like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CAR")
public class Office {
   ....
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "IDPERSON")
   Person owner;

}
```

The issue I encounter is that **I cannot create an attribute linked to a Mapped-Superclass**.

Of course, I could solve this issue simply by defining Person as an *entity* and declaring it to be **InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE** and Woman and Man with a **discriminator** this way they could share the same table and it will work. However, this solution is **not possible** for me because the **data is already there** and there are **many dependencies** from it, so I cannot change the WOMAN or MAN table.

Is there a way to use a discriminator in this case too, so that Hibernate will know in which table it has to look for the person?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So I couldn't find any way to tell hibernate to use a discriminator on a specific attribute.

So what I did, I created a Gender Enum

```
enum Gender {
  WOMAN, MAN;
}
```

And I added it as an attribute of a Car. I also wired the woman and the man service and created a getter method for the owner that will decide which service to use based on gender.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CAR")
public class Office {
   ....
   @Column(name = "PERSONID")
   Long personId;
   @Column(name = "GENDER")
   Gender gender;

   @Autowired
   @Transient
   WomanService womanService;

   @Autowired
   @Transient
   ManService manService;

   Optional<Person> getOwner(){
      switch(gender){
         case WOMAN: return womanService.findById(personId);
         case MAN: return manService.findById(personId);
         default: return Optional.empty();
      }
   }
}
```

I'm aware this solution sucks but it's the best I could come up with to avoid redefining other entities.